# camlQuery rowlimit not working on a list

Tags: 2010, client-object-model, jquery, caml-query, caml

I'm trying to update some elements in a list with client object and caml query. It's working, my values are updated, but for all the items (around 15) even I have a rowlimit of 5 :

```
var collListItemToBeUpdated = "";
    var listItemToBeUpdated = "";
    function getItemsToBeUpdated() //this function called on button click to get ID's
    {
         var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
         var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Matériel Recyclage');
         var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
         camlQuery.set_viewXml("<Query> <OrderBy> <FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /> </OrderBy> </Query> ");
         camlQuery.RowLimit = 5;
         collListItemToBeUpdated = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
         clientContext.load(collListItemToBeUpdated);
         clientContext.executeQueryAsync(getItemsToBeUpdatedSuccess, getItemsToBeUpdatedFailed);
    }
    function getItemsToBeUpdatedSuccess()
    {
         ListItemToBeUpdated= collListItemToBeUpdated.getEnumerator();
         updateMultipleListItems();
    }
    function getItemsToBeUpdatedFailed(sender, args)
    {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }

    function updateMultipleListItems() //this function called on successfully getting ID's
    {   
        var itemArray = [];
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Matériel Recyclage');

         while(ListItemToBeUpdated.moveNext())
         {
            var oItem = ListItemToBeUpdated.get_current();
            var oListItem = oList.getItemById(oItem.get_id());
            oListItem.set_item('Palette', '1');  
            oListItem.update();
            itemArray.push(oListItem);
            clientContext.load(itemArray[itemArray.length-1]);
         }  
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(updateMultipleListItemsSuccess, updateMultipleListItemsFailed);
    }
    function updateMultipleListItemsSuccess() 
    {    
        alert('Items Updated');
    }

    function updateMultipleListItemsFailed(sender, args) 
    {    
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```

Can you tell me why the RowLimit attribute isn't working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[SP.CamlQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245851.aspx) does not have a property `RowLimit` , you have to set in the caml markup:

```
  camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query> <OrderBy> <FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /> </OrderBy> </Query> <RowLimit>5</RowLimit> </View>");
```

Comment: that's exactly what I've found just one minute ago ;)